# static const member initialization from file

Tags: c++, static, initialization, constants

How do you initialize a static const member with a value that is stored in a file? For example:

```
Class Foo
{
private:
  static const String DataFromFile;
  void InitData (void);
};
```

I know for a short value, I can initialize with:

```
const String DataFromFile = "Some Value";
```

But what if the value is really a "big" value and encrypted and stored in a disk file? I need to decrypt it before putting it into `DataFromFile`.

Is there a way to do it or can I just forget it and treat it as a regular variable? That is, instead of:

```
static const String DataFromFile;
```

can I just declare it as:

```
String DataFromFile;
```

and initialize it with a function?

Comment: You can initialize it with a function in any case, whether it's const or static or both or neither.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> How do you initialize a static const member with a value that is
>   stored in a file? For example:

Like this:

```
//X.h
#include <string>
class X
{
  //...
  static const std::string cFILE_TEXT_;
  static const bool cINIT_ERROR_;
};

//X.cpp
//...#include etc...
#include <fstream>
#include <stdexcept>

namespace {    
std::string getTextFromFile( const std::string& fileNamePath )
{
  std::string fileContents;
  std::ifstream myFile( fileNamePath.c_str() );
  if( !(myFile >> fileContents) );
  {
    return std::string();
  }
  return fileContents;
}
}

const std::string X::cFILE_TEXT_( getTextFromFile( "MyPath/MyFile.txt" ) );
const bool X::cINIT_ERROR_( cFILE_TEXT_.empty() );

X::X()
{ 
  if( cINIT_ERROR_ )
  { 
   throw std::runtime_error( "xxx" ); 
  }
}
```

Comment: `static std::string fileStr_;` - should that have a `const` in it?

Comment: Why would it not compile? No, no C++11 features here. I've just compiled it at http://ideone.com/izpQlU

Comment: Yep! - comment cheerfully withdrawn (with up-vote)...  I've just never seen this before; it felt like I'd tried this in the past, and gotten a compile error.

Comment: It might be worth noting in your answer that the std::runtime_error thrown in `getTextFromfile` might be difficult to deal with, if the static initialization is done before `main()`

Comment: @Tom: I'm wondering what would happen. I imagine the program would terminate, in which case one could output a message in the terminate handler, but can one be sure that the std::iostream classes are initialized yet. I'm not sure, I'll have to look into it.

Comment: OK. If an exception is thrown during initialization of non-local variables/constants with static or thread storage duration, then std::terminate will be called. This is not so bad, depending on the requirements. An alternative would be to initialize another static constant in the event of an error, and delay the throw to construction. Example modified...